# Cannot open User profile service application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

I want to run the user profile service application on a SharePoint 2013 Farm. When I create the service, I cannot open it, there is an 'Unexpected error'. When I try to run the User Profile Synchronization service, it stuck on running. I have tried these:

- resetting IIS
- Stopping the service from Powershell and starting again
- changing the Farm account and also the SharePoint account
- adding the account to local users group

There is also one more error about the Forefront Identity Manager, which has been mentioned here: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx
as a test to check if the whole profile service is working or not, I receive an error : Your account is not a member of a required security group

My account should be part of which groups? Or there is another problem?
It might be a service account issue, but I don't know exactly what is the problem. I have the following permissions for my account but the default managed account is something else:

SharePoint Server Search

User Profile Synchronization Service

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Application Pool: SharePoint

Farm Account

Search App

### User Profile app

Update:
Found the problem.

I had to reenter the credentials in IIS pools for the related ones.

Comment: Is your account is part of local Administrator group? if not then add it...after that logoff and log in back so that permission properly synced

Comment: have you tried deleting the user profile service and reprovisioning a new service application. Also, that sounds like it may be a service account issue, with one of your service accounts having a changed password, and restarting may fix that.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE yes it is part of the local admin and I have already tried the logoff and on again

Comment: @Mike yes, I have tried recreating that many times. It might be a service account issue, but I don't know exactly what is the problem. I have the following permissions for my account but the default managed account is something else:    SharePoint Server Search
User Profile Synchronization Service
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Application Pool: SharePoint 
Farm Account
Search App
User Profile app

Comment: Is ur account is farm admin? Account which is running timer service?